# Deleting specific vertex in polygon in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, arctoolbox, vertices

I use ArcGIS 10.3 and I have many  Building consist of window and wall but my problems that windows are not on straighter the wall so I search tool help me to delete corner vertex of window because i have more buildings [image]

Comment: snap http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001v00000007000000 might do it for you if the walls terminate at the window otherwise Ian Yau has it correct, clip the windows with the walls to eliminate the extra area outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses Minimum Bounding Geometry.

Assumptions:

- Wall widths are uniform
- Access to an Advanced Licence
- Walls can be identified (grouped) by building as an attribute
- Buildings have no acute external angles (less than 90 degrees. see example below)

---

Steps:

1. Use the tool 'Minimum Bounding Geometry' with these parameters: geometry type = Convex Hull , group option = List , group field = {this is the field that identifies each building}
2. Result will create polygons that represent the boundary of the exterior walls. See example:[image: exterior wall]
3. Use the 'Buffer Wizard' with the wall width as your buffer distance. See instructions here: http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011497
4. This will create a polygons that represent the full width of the interior walls. See Example (brown polygon):

   [image: internal wall]
5. Use the tool 'Erase' with these parameters: Input Features = minimum bounding geometry polygon (black dashes in example) , Erase Features = interior walls polygon (brown in example). **The result will be your new window polygon.** See Example:

   [image: new windows]

Example of acute external angle:

[image: acute angle]

Answer (score 3):

You can [Delete Vertex](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-existing-features/deleting-a-vertex.htm) manually, if you want, from the editor tools.  Deleting vertex tool can delete a vertex or multiple vertices at a time to reshape the feature. To do that:

1. Click the Edit tool on the Editor toolbar and double-click
   the feature you want to edit
2. Click the Delete Vertex tool on the Edit Vertices toolbar and click
   the vertex you want to delete.
3. If you want to delete multiple vertices, click the Delete Vertex tool on the Edit Vertices toolbar and drag a box around the vertices.
4. Save edits.

The link above shows also the icons in the Edit Vertices toolbar that you can use to accomplish your task.

Answer (score 2):

If the walls and windows are separate features and the walls and windows overlap, Clip (ArcToolbox/Analysis Tools/Extract) the window features using the wall features.

Comment: The windows isn't overlap with wall ، the window start when wall end